Small debris which has punctured a tubeless tire: to leave or to remove?
I punctured tubeless road tire. The puncture self-sealed in a few minutes. At home, I found the glass bit and pulled it out (as I would have done with tube setup). This has opened about 3mm cut, looks like it doesn't self-seal now and more work is needed (repairing or even replacing the tire).
Did I do the wrong thing removing the debris - should it have been left in place "as long as everything worked"?

This question is similar to: Is 3mm tubeless puncture too big to seal?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Note that some sealant (like Silca's) also contain fibers that allows them to clog bigger hole than 3mm.

@renaud I read this one as "should I remove foreign debris from a tubeless puncture where the sealant has worked?"  and less about the size of the hole.   I have no idea what the answer should be,

@Rеnаud As Criggie noted, I'm not asking whether my puncture is too big to seal - in this case I already know that it is.

IMHO the big risk with leaving it in the tyre is that it could come out at the wrong moment or do further damage and then no longer seal. If you remove it at home and it seals nicely you at least have some confidence that it’s going to stay that way. If it doesn’t seal you have more options (including mounting a new tyre, installing a tube etc.)

You should remove them, I can think of two main reasons:

sharp debris like glass can cause additional damage if not removed, so should definitely be removed.
you have much less guarantee that the bounding between the debris and the sealant is optimal. Removing the debris when you arrive provides better warranties, as you use products that are designed to work together and that are installed in a controlled environment.
and also, some large debris (I discover for example hawthorn thorns last time I unmounted my tires - about 15mm) can interfere with the rim, which can come out for "mechanical" reasons, if you hit an obstacle at the location of the debris.

And it's also a good opportunity to check if you haven't lost too much sealant, and top up if needed.
